# Trouble creating a numerical column based on an existing categorical column

Tags: r

I have trouble creating a numerical column (`NicePch`) based on an existing categorical column (`data$vegetation`), containing values "mats" or "seeds".

```
> NicePch <- data$vegetation

> class(data$vegetation)
[1] "factor"


> class(NicePch)
[1] "factor"
```

Now, I would like to replace the "mats" values with 1, and "seeds" values with 16.

```
> NicePch[data$vegetation=="mats"] <- 1
```

But I get the following warning message:

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, data$vegetation == "mats", value = 1) : invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I am not sure how to overcome this.

Comment: Does this factor contain two levels only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NicePch <- c(1, 16)[match(data$vegetation, c("mats", "seeds"))]
```

The problem is you start defining `NicePch` as a factor with specific levels (whatever values there are in `data$vegetation`, so when you try to add a value that isn't one of the levels (e.g. 1 as you did), you get the error from the factor.

Here, we map maps/seeds to values 1 or 2 with `match`, and then use that to pick from `c(1, 16)`.  Here is an example:

```
data <- data.frame(vegetation=c("mats", "seeds", "seeds", "mats", "alligators"))
(NicePch <- c(1, 16)[match(data$vegetation, c("mats", "seeds"))])
# [1]  1 16 16  1 NA
```

Comment: +1 For an approach that works with more than two factor levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach if your factor has exactly two levels:

```
NicePch <- 1 + (data$vegetation == "seeds") * 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NicePch <- ifelse(data$vegetation == "mats", 1, 16)
```